# Telerik RadRibbonBar strange behaviour

Tags: c#, telerik, visual-studio-2013

While setting buttons (text, images and both text and image alignments) in the RibbonBar (Windows form, Telerik v2014.1.228.40, Visual Studio 2013, C#), it suddenly becomes too small, without a way to increase the size. It is a project being done for several weeks and was working very well for previous telerik and VS releases. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a known error in this Telerik WInForms v2014.1 release that occurs only when the form has WindowsState = Maximized at design time. Fix: set maximize state at runtime only.